# How can I override skin's settings through code?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I have a Firefox extension that changes a browser's tab color like this:

```js
tabBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes[i].style.backgroundColor = "#8f8";
```

This code works fine in my development profile, but in the working profile I have a theme installed (Noia 2.0 eXtreme), that sets its own appearance for the tabs, so my code can not change the tab's color. Is it possible to override the theme's settings through the code?

I just do not get it. I have found the skin's CSS file, it seems pretty simple.

```css
tab {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    padding: 1px 5px 2px 7px;
    border-top: 1px  solid;
    border-right: 2px solid;
    border-left: 1px solid;
    -moz-border-top-colors: #FFFFFF;
    -moz-border-right-colors: #808080 #404040;
    -moz-border-left-colors: #FFFFFF;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
    background-color: #CDCED3;
    color: #606060;
    min-height: 20px !important
}
tab[selected="true"] {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 1px 7px 4px 9px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-image : url("chrome://browser/skin/icons/Bookmark-background.png") !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
}
tab:hover {
    color: #000000 !important;
}
```

Setting

```js
tabBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes[i].style.setProperty("background-image", "none", "important");
```

Comment: try using dom inspector: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/ you can open chrome document position to the element (tab) and see how it derived style it derived. That might give you some additional information. Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: Thank you, Mihailo, for the hint, I will give it a try. I was hoping there might be some universal way to solve such a problem. I am certain with some tricky tweaking I can beat one particular skin, but it would be great to be able to override any such settings through the code, to be certain that the problem will not occur with some other skin.

Comment: btw, you're calling this from overlay code? XUL, or maybe from XBL (crazy question - but I had some issues with styling in XBL)

Comment: Hi, Mihailo. Yes, my code comes from an overlay. I have main extension window, which has an overlay, which is XUL, which has its JavaScript code in an external file. That is where the code comes from. I am lost. I start to think there might be a bug in the Firefox :-( The documentation says that the code provided in the answer should override the settings in the CSS, but apparently it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CSSStyleDeclaration you could use:

```
tabBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes[i].style.setProperty("background-color", "#8f8", "important");
```

Comment: Possibly instead just using `tabBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes[i].style.setProperty("background-color", "#8f8 !important");` would work as well?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, guys, unfortunately none of them works so far. This one tabBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes[i].style.setProperty("background-color", "#8f8 !important"); produces an error: not enough arguments. The former one: tabBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes[i].style.setProperty("background-color", "#8f8", "important"); works fine without the skin, but fails to change anything with the skin :-( What could possibly cause this problem ???

Comment: Computer broke ... had to fix ... restarted everything ... cleaned the display ... now the code works! Probably the dusting did it :-) Thanks everybody for the help.